# How to remove whitespace before div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do some basic web development, but for some reason, there is a huge whitespace between the opening body tag and the first div. How do I move the div to the top /or remove whitespace/ without using 'position: fixed;'?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top_bar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(179, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_bar">
  generic string
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you don't need to use the `<style>` tags in your code snippet. If you remove the `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>` tags your code snippet will display the result you've intended to achieve.

Comment: I'm printing this over CGI and I forgot to remove them - i need them for localhost. The white stripe is still there, I even tried the next answer with "*{ declarations }"

Answer (score 2):

That is because html, by default has 8px margin. To remove it, use the code below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top_bar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(179, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_bar">
  generic string
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Try It Once

Comment: https://anonmgur.com/up/60edb44728a61587e4f4e7403ba93e1d.png

Still stuck at this

Comment: For some reason it doesn't do anything, as the page is still at that state.

*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
 html, body
 {
  width:  100%;
  height:  auto;
  margin:  0px;
  padding:  0px;
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer, so people know what it does and how to apply it to their problem :-)

Comment: sure for next time I will be

Comment: Why not this time?

Comment: @SantoshKhalse you can use the [edit] link to fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post, but apparently I forgot to remove the extra newlines from the header that I send with CGI. It worked out properly.